# Get average value from NSManagedObject request array

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate, nsmanagedobject

I need to get an average price from my `NSManagedObject` array.
I have executed `NSFetchRequest` and retrieved an array of objects close to users location. 
What I want to do now is to get the average price from this fetch result. I have tried by retrieving `NSNumber` object like this

```
NSNumber *average = [resultArray valueForKeyPath:@"@avg.price"];
// always return 0
```

Tried with KVC by accessing the variable through my `NSManagedObject` class name like

```
NSNumber *average = [resultArray valueForKeyPath:@"Product.@avg.price"];
// returned an error -[NSNull decimalValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Couldn't get it to work with `NSPredicate` as well, fighting with this all day now and can't get my head around it. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us the code of your fetchRequest?

Comment: The problem is not in the fetch request as I said I've an array with `NSManagedObjects` already, just want to compute the average price from this array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to prepend the `@avg` operator with `Product`.

Use `NSNumber *average = [resultArray valueForKeyPath:@"@avg.price"];` and you should be fine.

For more info on KVC Collection Operators, such as `@avg`, `@sum` and others, refer to this excellent [NSHipster article](http://nshipster.com/kvc-collection-operators/).

Comment: Feel like a dumbass now. It's all working just I had a typo in my key path which was why this `NSNumber` was always 0. All fixed and working now. Thanks very much :)